# cocos2d : How to clone a CCNode hierarchy

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, clone, hierarchy, ccnode

I try to clone a CCNode hierarchy, the problems is I need to reset and set all the variable by type, can I have a way to do that more automatically ?

basiclly what I want to do is :
- store a CCNode* (with some child, for example an image at Pos 10-10, and a Label at Pos 100-50 with the text "Test");
- then clone it, for get a new CCNode* with the same default value and childs.

I need to copy it, because after they will get modify, is like a template of Node, before get custom value.

If you know a simple way to copy, and set all the hierarchy (with correct type also), without big if/else statement for each kind of type, it will help me a lot ^^

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This code clones CCNode and all child CCNodes recursively. You can add other subclasses and other properties to copy.

```
+ (CCNode*) cloneCCNode:(CCNode*)source
{
    CCNode* clone = [CCNode node];
    for (CCNode* srcSubnode in source.children) {

        CCNode* subnode;

        if ([srcSubnode isKindOfClass:[CCSprite class]]) { //only CCSprites are copied, add other subclasses if you need to
            CCSprite* srcSprite = (CCSprite*)srcSubnode;
            subnode = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:srcSprite.texture];
            ((CCSprite*)subnode).displayFrame = srcSprite.displayFrame;
        } else {
            subnode = [self cloneCCNode:srcSubnode];
        }

        subnode.rotation = srcSubnode.rotation;
        subnode.position = srcSubnode.position;
        subnode.anchorPoint = srcSubnode.anchorPoint;
        subnode.zOrder = srcSubnode.zOrder;
        [clone addChild:subnode];
    }
    return clone;
}
```